# How to enable required for multiple uRadioButtons? HTML

Tags: html

Currently, I have a question and 3 options with them being radio buttons. So far the required statements do not work to show the red asterisk, is there something im doing wrong with the required?

```
<div class="form-group">
                <fieldset class="no-bt-margin">
                  <legend class="fs-14">
                    Question 1. What is your name?
                  </legend>
                  <uRadioButton ID="rbIntentToDoWithPayment1" FieldName="rbIntentToDoWithPayment1" GroupName="CHCK" Required="true" ShowAsRequired="true" Text="Value 3"
                    ReqDependency="rblDidEmprContributeToPension=Y;rbIntentToDoWithPayment2=N;rbIntentToDoWithPayment3=N" ReqDependencyType="All" EnableBootstrapButtons="True"/>
                  <uRadioButton ID="rbIntentToDoWithPayment2" FieldName="rbIntentToDoWithPayment2" GroupName="CHCK" Text="Value 2" EnableBootstrapButtons="True"/>
                  <uRadioButton ID="rbIntentToDoWithPayment3" FieldName="rbIntentToDoWithPayment3" GroupName="CHCK" Text="Value 1" EnableBootstrapButtons="True"/>
               </fieldset>
              </div>
```

Comment: this is HTML ..

Comment: oopseeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: i think its <input type="radio" id="ID" name="inputName"  value="Value1" required>